# Jquery: change colour to table row when select option is changed not working multiple table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right, i have got a table, with two rows. In the right cell i have a drop down menu with the values (1, 2 and 3).

Depending on with is selected i want the table row its in to change a specific colour. I have managed to get this to work when i have one table row and it works fine changing between values. However when i copy my code to make multiple lines it stops workin.

with multiple rows, if i click value 2 on the first it changes the first row too the correct colour, then if i change the value say on row 5, no matter what value i choose it will change to the colour of the first row i changed. If that makes sense.

Heres the code......

-

CSS

```
<style>
table td,th{ 
    border:1px solid black; 
    padding-left:100px; 
}


table tr{ 
    background-color:red;
} 
.online{ 
    background-color:green;
}
.offline{ 
    background-color:red;
}
.paused{ 
    background-color:orange;
}
</style>
```

-

HTML

```
<body>
<table id="table">
<tr style="background-color:grey;">
    <th>
    Hello
    </th>

    <th>
    Is it
    </th>
</tr>   

<tr class="options">
    <td>
    yayaya
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr class="options">
    <td>
    yayaya
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
```

-

JQUERY

```
<script>
$('select').change(function(){ 
    if($('select').val() == "2"){ 
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('online');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('offline');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('paused');
        $(this).parents('.options').addClass('online'); 
    }else if($('select').val() == "1"){
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('online');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('offline');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('paused');
         $(this).parents('.options').addClass('offline'); 
    }else if($('select').val() == "3"){
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('online');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('offline');
                $(this).parents('.options').removeClass('paused');
         $(this).parents('.options').addClass('paused'); 
    }
});
</script>
```

here it is on jsfiddle so that you can see what i mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/n3nFB/1923/

try it with one row and then copy and past the same row underneath

Comment: you want to use `$(this).val()` otherwise you are getting the val of all selects.  Also not sure if this is a lazy paste thing but your select ids should be unique

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n3nFB/1929/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `$('select').val()` to `this.value` so that you use the one that was altered and not the first one always..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n3nFB/1924/

---

Also, you can remove multiple classes with one call, and you can chain the following `addClass`

for example

```
$(this).parents('.options')
       .removeClass('online offline paused')
       .addClass('online');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n3nFB/1925/

Comment: or $(this).val() to keep it jquery.

Comment: not need to, since he has access the the raw object and `value` is a property of it.

Comment: not needed, but its the jquery way, so probably more readable.

Comment: @LaurensKling, the jquery way is not to wrap everything in jquery objects. If you can safely (*cross-browser*) and without extra steps use native code then it is always advisable to do it (*performance-wise and clarity-wise*).

Comment: it doesnt work with val(), but its works with .value    This has helped me and i will use it, but as i am learning jquery at the minute does anyone know i can acheive this whith the .val()?

Comment: @matthewsmart `.val()` will work as laurens mentioned, but you need to wrap `this` in a jquery object like this `$(this).val()` (demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n3nFB/1931/)

Comment: Sure it's unneeded extra wrapping and less quick, but if you are new to javascript and learning jquery, it might be the more readable way to go, thats what i was trying to say.

Comment: @LaurensKling, personally i find `this.value` more readable than `$(this).val()`

Comment: Everyone their style :) But now Matthew has 2 options to choose from :)